# how to upload images to images.google.com from my computer?

Tags: image, google-chrome

I have images with me. I want to upload the images to images.google.com But i am not unable to upload the photos. If i type one of my friend name in search bar in images.google.com, easily iam able to see his images first. But please let me know how to upload the images so that even if any one type my name in images.google.com,let my images are visible? Please help me out of this? Even i have seen so many posts and i had made too much surfing but i am unable to upload the images.Even i tried from Google+, i didnot found the solution over there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upload images directly to google images. To make your picture appears on this platform, the best you can do is to upload your picture with alt tag and title as your name on some webpage or blog which is publicly available and can be indexed by google. But, even after doing that I can't say surely that your picture will appear in  search results of images.google.com until google recognize it as  relevant enough for your name keyword. But, in my experience names are usually not too common in search so chances are more that it will appear in 4-6 weeks.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Tried and uploaded an image from blog.

Comment: My pleasure, now please make sure that you submit your url to https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url?pli=1 , this will inform google about your page